# define variables to hold intrinsic parameters

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using OpenCV with c++ to calibrate a stereo camera.
I calculated the intrinsic and distortions parameters of both cameras using `cvCalibrateCamera2()` then I stored them.
I want to load them back to perform stereo camera calibration using `cvStereoCalibrate`.
how can I define the variables that will contain the intrinsic and distortion parameters of both cameras?

Comment: Can you give a concise and minimal sample of what you have tried, and why it didn't work for you in code please? You could well have a class controlling two cameras properly synchronized.

Answer (score 2):

The intrinsic and distortion parameters are just matrices, so the easiest way to store and reload them is by writing the to a yaml file:

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/xml_yaml_persistence.html